# Explanation of the purely projective definition of a conic section

Tags: definition, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The definition is : ***A conic is the locus of the intersections of corresponding lines in two projectively related pencils .***

this is based on: ***for any four given points on a straight line appear under the same cross-ratio from any fifth point O*** -  where in the case of a conic section the point is only free to move along the cone.

I have problems tying these two statements together because I can't grasp the concept of constructing it which is:

construct two points *O & O'* that have the property of  ***biunique correspondence*** between the pencils of lines coming from them where: a line *a* coming from *O* meets a line *a'* coming from *O'* that lies on the cone.

*ex. for projectively related pencils*

[image]

***The two pencils of lines in this state have the same cross ratio.***

I'd love to be provided by a proof to that and\ or it's significance to the definition of the conic section along with definition \ explanation\ examples to biunique correspondence .

PS : My source is the book What is Mathematics from where the statements in bold are quoted.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "the point is only free to move **along the cone.**"; Why this reference to a cone ? We have no need for it when doing **plane projective geometry**. The name "conic section"  must not make you think that we need a reference to a cone; this reference - I would say - has only an historical interest, unless you do spatial projective geometry.

Comment: that's a very interesting piece of information. here i only paraphrased what i read tho.